# Export and Import storm kafka zookeeper offset from HDP 2.2 to new HDP 2.4

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform

I have storm topology running in HDP 2.2 with kafka spout and I have another new HDP 2.4 cluster setup. How I can export and import storm-kafka offset from HDP 2.2 cluster to new HDP 2.4 cluster ?

I have tried with kafka utils but storm stores offset in different directory structure.

Is there any utility to import/export storm kafka zookeeper offset ?

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I used [zkCopy](https://github.com/kshchepanovskyi/zkcopy)